# Search params for server components in Next JS 13 app directory

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

When using the file structure app -> explore -> page.tsx and using the following code to get the search params:

```
export default function ExplorePage({ searchParams }: { searchParams: { search: string | undefined } }) {
  const { search } = searchParams
```

I can not run npm run build. It gives this error:

```
Type error: Page "app/explore/page.tsx" does not match the required types of a Next.js Page.
  Invalid configuration:
    The exported page component isn't correctly typed.
        Expected "{ searchParams: { search: any; }; }", got "PageProps".
          Invalid configuration:
            Expected "{ search: any; }", got "Record<string, string | string[]> | undefined".
              Expected "{ search: any; }", got "undefined".
```

However, I can run the site with npm run dev and it works fine without errors.

Here are the version numbers from the package.json file:

```
"next": "13.0.0",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-dom": "18.2.0",
```

Now, what I am doing wrong to get this error? Next Js 13 is brand new and the app directory is still in beta so it might be a bug.

I have tried:

- Testing different types to see if the error had something to do with this setup.
- Tried first to use the Next Router which of course did not work since this is a server component.

Comment: I'm getting the same thing. It happens when I introduce another level of routing, which worked fine in the existing pages format. `app -> bingwallpapers -> [id] -> page.tsx`
This all works fine.

But when I introduce another page:

`app -> bingwallpapers -> tags -> [tag] -> page.tsx`

The build fails

Answer (score 10):

try this

```js
type Props = {
  params?: {
    num?: string;
  };
  searchParams?: {
    search?: string;
  };
};

export default function Page(props: Props) {...}
```

- change `searchParams` to `searchParams?`
- change `search: string | undefined` to `search?: string` <- bug?

It works perfectly for me

Answer (score 0):

Append `export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'` to your page.

I was getting the same error, searchParams worked in dev mode, but not in prod.

e.g.

```
type Props = {
  searchParams?: {
    s?: string;
  };
};
export default async function Page(params: Props) {
  // ...
}
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'
```

More on [segment configs](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/segment-config#dynamic).